# Перенос строки в python

Tags: python, вывод

[image: скрин:]
Как сделать так, чтобы каждая строка в консоли выводилась в одну строчку, так как выделенная синим ? (end='') не работает !

Comment: Rstrip для content[3]?

Comment: Код нужно приводить текстом, а не скриншотом, ну и файл с входными данными хорошо бы продемонстрировать, хотя бы частично.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте строку  **from __future__ import print_function**
 перед всеми импортами. А после уже делаем так:

**print**(*выводимые данные*, end = ' ')

Comment: Но зачем? У ТС `Python 3.7`.

Comment: @nomnoms12 так если python 3.7 то end должен работать, или я чего то не понимаю?